# Split vendor and app when using react-hot

Tags: reactjs, webpack

I am using react-hot plugin with webpack, and it works after I follow the instruction:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: [
        'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090',
        'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
        './src/index'
    ],
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        }]
    }
};
```

The generated `/static/bundle.js` contains all the libraries.

While I want to split the vendors from my application, so I tried to add multiple entry points:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index'],
        vendor: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        }]
    }
};
```

However the /static/app.bundle.js still contain the `jquery,react...`.

Is this possible?

---

Update this is the config which can work as expected after @zerkms mentioned that the vendors must be declared explicitly:

```
module.exports = {
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index'],
        vendor: [
            'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8090',
            'webpack/hot/only-dev-server', 'react', 'jquery'
        ]
    },
    output: {
        path: path.join(__dirname, 'dist'),
        filename: 'app.bundle.js',
        publicPath: '/static/'
    },
    plugins: [
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
        new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin('vendor', 'vendor.bundle.js')
    ],
    module: {
        loaders: [{
            test: /\.js$/,
            loaders: ['react-hot', 'babel'],
            include: path.join(__dirname, 'src')
        }]
    }
};
```

Comment: `vendor: ['jquery', 'react']`

Comment: How about the `webpack/hot/only-dev-server`?

Comment: I don't use hot-reload so not sure. But if you want to extract some libraries to their own bundle you must enumerate them explicitly (you're warned though that every one of them will be initialised (run) even if not used)

Comment: Thanks, it worked. See my update.